# Async/Await Error returned Promise { <pending> }

Tags: node.js, async-await, mysql2

Please help me, what is the way ouput to display 1 or 0

```
const checkDataFail = async () => {
    const result = await conn.promise().query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE id = '10'")
        .then( ([rows,fields]) => {
        return rows && rows.length ? "1" : "0";
    })
    .catch(console.log);

    return result;
}

console.log(checkDataFail());
```

Output: Promise { < pending> }

Comment: Why are you using `then()` on `conn.promise().query` if you are putting `await` in front of it? Just go for `return result && result.length ? "1" : "0";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's easy, your function is an async function, which is to say it always returns a promise.

You'd have to `await` the response before outputting to console.

```
(async function() {
    console.log(await checkDataFail())
})()
```

Answer (score 1):

`async/await` is a nice little wrapper AROUND a promise. Inside is where you'll want to work with the data as the return from an `async` function gets wrapped into a promise. If you REALLY want to use `async/await`, operate on your promise inside of it:

```
const checkDataFail = async () => {
  try {
    const [rows, fields] = await conn.promise().query('...'); // Promise#then()
    return rows && rows.length ? "1" : "0";
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e); // Promise#catch()
  }
}
```

This would return the exact same results as your code above and as you can see it really combines just a few steps.

More information about Promises can be easily found, but since it looks like you know about then, know that `await` inside an `async`function *waits* for the promise result and unpacks it. You can still use then and catches for specific adaptions and handling, but `await` *waits* so if all you need is the raw result of the promise and you want to use a `try/catch` block you can.

[More information on `async/await` can be found on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)